# Extracting rows from dataframe with conditions on multiple specific columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, selection

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
         cat  dog  cow   X   box  bag
trait1    0    0    0    1    0    0               
trait2    1    0    1    2    0    0
trait3    0    0    0    0    0    0
trait4    1    3    1    1    0    0
trait5    0    0    0    1    2    1
trait6    0    0    0    1    0    0
trait7    0    0    0    1    0    1
```

1. From `df`, I would like to extract all traits for which `X` is unique, in this case `trait1` and `trait6`.
2. In addition, I would like to extract all traits that `X` shares uniquely with animals or objects. For animals: `trait2` and `trait4`. For objects: `trait5` and `trait7`

I have tried something like this:

```
animals<-c('cat','dog','cow')
objects<-c('box','bag')
df[df[,animals]==0 & df[,objects]==0 & df[,X]>=1, ]   # To get traits unique for X
df[df[,animals]>=1 & df[,objects]==0 & df[,X]>=1, ]   # To get traits unique for X and animals
df[df[,animals]==0 & df[,objects]==1 & df[,X]>=1, ]   # To get traits unique for X and objects
```

But that didn't go quite as planned.

Comment: Can you please update your post with the desired output. I think you need to clarify your selection criteria. E.g. in which way is 'X' unique for 'trait1' and 'trait5'?

Comment: My mistake, X was of course unique for trait1 and trait6. Edited it now

Comment: In which way is 'X' unique for 'trait1' and 'trait6'? Again, please update your post with the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler version, same results:

```
animal.trait <- apply(df[, animals], 1, any)
obj.trait <- apply(df[, objects], 1, any)

df[!(obj.trait | animal.trait) & df$X, ]
#        cat dog cow X box bag
# trait1   0   0   0 1   0   0
# trait6   0   0   0 1   0   0
df[animal.trait & df$X, ]
#        cat dog cow X box bag
# trait2   1   0   1 2   0   0
# trait4   1   3   1 1   0   0
df[obj.trait & df$X, ]
#        cat dog cow X box bag
# trait5   0   0   0 1   2   1
# trait7   0   0   0 1   0   1
```

This is my understanding of what you want.  A trait is unique to X if X is the only column to have a value greater than zero.  A trait is shared between X and Animals if any of the Animals columns have a value greater than zero, and X has a value greater than zero.  Same logic for object-X trait sharing.

To understand why your logic doesn't work, examine your interim conditions.  For example, in:

```
df[df[,animals]==0 & df[,objects]==0 & df[,X]>=1, ]
```

If you look at `df[,animals]==0`, you get:

```
#          cat   dog   cow
# trait1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# trait2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# trait3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# trait4 FALSE FALSE FALSE
# trait5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# trait6  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# trait7  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Which is probably not what you thought you were getting.  Presumably you were hoping to get a 7 length vector, not this matrix.  In order to get the vector you need to use `apply` to go through each row, and do the comparisons on a per row basis.

---

OLD VERSION

This should do what you want, though I don't understand why for the first one you include trait 5 instead of 6.

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(y) y["X"] >= 1 & all(y[names(y) != "X"] == 0)),]
df[apply(df, 1, function(y) any(y[animals]>=1) & !any(y[objects]>=1) & y["X"] >=1),]
df[apply(df, 1, function(y) any(y[objects]>=1) & !any(y[animals]>=1) & y["X"] >=1),]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! It is exactly as you said.

Comment: @JoranMartijn, to the extent this answers your question, please consider marking this answer as the solution.